# Determine number of rows for a variable to return to a previous value

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame with yearly values for above-ground biomass for different pixels. Each of these pixels have had a disturbance applied to them. I want to determine how many rows it takes for each pixel to return to its pre-disturbance value, but I'm not sure how to go about doing this.

Here's some example data:

```
pixel.no <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
year <- c(1995,1996,1997,1998,1999,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,
          1995,1996,1997,1998,1999,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004)
disturbed <- c("No","No","No","Yes","No","No","No","No","No","No",
               "No","No","Yes","No","No","Yes","No","No","No","No")
AGB <- c(200,204,205,150,155,170,190,205,202,207,
         180,181,100,110,150,130,150,160,180,200)

data <- data.frame(pixel.no,year,disturbed,AGB)
print(data)
   pixel.no year disturbed AGB
1         1 1995        No 200
2         1 1996        No 204
3         1 1997        No 205
4         1 1998       Yes 150
5         1 1999        No 155
6         1 2000        No 170
7         1 2001        No 190
8         1 2002        No 205
9         1 2003        No 202
10        1 2004        No 207
11        2 1995        No 180
12        2 1996        No 181
13        2 1997       Yes 100
14        2 1998        No 110
15        2 1999        No 150
16        2 2000       Yes 130
17        2 2001        No 150
18        2 2002        No 160
19        2 2003        No 180
20        2 2004        No 200
```

For every instance where "disturbed" = Yes, I want to count the number of rows until the value for AGB returns to equal to or greater than the value for the previous year. So for the above data I would get:

[1] 4 2 3

Any suggestions for an efficient way to do this automatically in R across a large data frame?

Comment: I assume "4" means starting the _after_ the first `disturbed=="Yes"`, four more years passed until the pre-disturbed value of 205 was met/exceeded. How do you get `2` and `3`? They don't follow the same convention.